# Visual Studio UI rendering issues

Tags: visual-studio

I'm facing issues with **rendering (User Interface) issues** when I try to open the Editor of an object. For instance, in SSIS, I'm trying to open the editor of task : The different boxes and drop drown lists are over the text, and as I am trying some new tools/tasks, I don't know what I am supposed to see.

Here is a sample of the error I'm facing :

[image]

Here is my setup : Windows 10 on an HP computer with Visual Studio 15.9.15, .NET Framework 4.8.03761

Comment: Try maximizing the window with the small square icon on the upper right.

Comment: Rendering is the same, if I try to maximize the window or if I change my display resolution.